# Abrir un fichero en modo lectura C

Tags: c, linux

estoy aprendiedno a programar en C. Me han pedido que haga un programa que preguntando al usuario el nombre de un fichero calcule su tamaño en bytes. Estoy en linux mint cinnamon, como dato. Adjunto el codigo y los comandos utilizados en la terminal para ejecutar el programa, gracias de antemano!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    FILE* f;    
    char* nombre;
    int cont;

    printf("Introduce el nombre del archivo cuyo tamanio quieres conocer: ");
    scanf("%s", nombre);
    f=fopen(nombre,"r");
    cont=0; 
    while(!feof(f)){
        cont=cont+1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("El archivo pesa %d bytes",cont);
    return 0;

}
```

Bien, ahora abro la terminal de linux para crear el ejecutable y ejecutarlo.

```
~/Escritorio$ gcc -o longFile longFile.c 
~/Escritorio$ ./longFile 
Introduce el nombre del archivo cuyo nombre quieres conocer: longFile.c
```

Bueno, se queda con el cursor parpadeando y no me devuelve ningun resultado.
Buscando por foros vi que hay que compilarlo con

```
~/Escritorio$ cc longFile.c -o longFile
```

Pero luego volviendo a poner

```
~/Escritorio$ ./longFile
```

me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo que he comentado antes, que no me devuelve nada.

Comment: Hola Daniel, no es problema de compilación, es de lógica del programa en sí, piensa en la condición de salida del ciclo.... ¿En algún momento lees bytes del archivo para que se alcance el end-of-file y feof no retorne 0?

Comment: FJSevilla, muchas gracias!! No me di cuenta

Comment: He leído que es muy conveniente compilar con gcc usando siempre la opción -Wall, que activa todos los los avisos más comunes, además, por supuesto, de los errores: gcc -Wall longFile.c -o longFile

Comment: Si encontraste la solución al problema, puedes publicar la respuesta y marcarla como correcta para que otros usuarios puedan consultarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaba añadir esto dentro del while para asi no estar en un bucle infinito

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    FILE* f;    
    char* nombre;
    int cont;
    int c;


    printf("Introduce el nombre del archivo cuyo tamanio quieres conocer: ");
    scanf("%s", nombre);
    f=fopen(nombre,"r");
    cont=0; 
    while(!feof(f)){
        c=fgetc(f); //ESTO ES LO QUE FALTABA
        cont=cont+1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("El archivo pesa %d bytes",cont);
    return 0;

}
```